# Is it possible to configure the number of list items shown when using %A formatting in F#?

Tags: f#, formatting

```
printfn "%A" [1..1000]
```

inside f# interactive shows

```
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19; 20; 21; 22;
23; 24; 25; 26; 27; 28; 29; 30; 31; 32; 33; 34; 35; 36; 37; 38; 39; 40; 41; 42;
43; 44; 45; 46; 47; 48; 49; 50; 51; 52; 53; 54; 55; 56; 57; 58; 59; 60; 61; 62;
63; 64; 65; 66; 67; 68; 69; 70; 71; 72; 73; 74; 75; 76; 77; 78; 79; 80; 81; 82;
83; 84; 85; 86; 87; 88; 89; 90; 91; 92; 93; 94; 95; 96; 97; 98; 99; 100; ...]
```

the following settings do not affect the number of list members shown

```
fsi.PrintSize <- 222        // no effect
fsi.PrintLength <- 222      // no effect
fsi.PrintDepth <- 222       // no effect
fsi.PrintWidth <- 222       // no effect
fsi.ShowIEnumerable <- true // no effect
```

1. Is it possible to configure the number of members shown **inside f# interactive**?
2. Is it possible t configure this such that (sprintf "%A") considers it **outside of f# interactive**?

i am asking this because i pretty print records, and currently some of the values are truncated. so the issue on top is to pretty print records without truncated values - just for context.

%A formatting has nice advantages as it nicely layouts records, which i do not want to loose by using StructuredFormatDisplayAttribute.

this formatting is part of formatting a large object with %A, which works perfectly, nicely without any effort. so i am not asking about really printing an isolated list.

---

inside the f# source:

checked the source code at https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/b23b2a0f99f12ece94c5ad89aabb9169d51091f3/src/fsharp/utils/sformat.fs

ObjectGraphFormatter apparently does the formatting, accepting format options.

the very last lines might be calling it:

```
let internal anyToStringForPrintf options (bindingFlags:BindingFlags) (value, typValue) = 
    let formatter = ObjectGraphFormatter(options, bindingFlags) 
    formatter.Format (ShowAll, value, typValue) |> layout_to_string options
```

which is called by the core Printf module which in turn is internal.

Comment: i found this: http://fssnip.net/cV/title/A-Generic-PrettyPrinter-for-Record-types which would be code similar to writing my own pretty printer. not yet prepared for that.

Comment: This is not an answer, but might be of interest: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/547

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/fsharp-interactive-options#customize-with-addprinter-and-addprinttransformer

Comment: thx scott, the issue does not hit it, but is of interest, as diving into %A clarifies the problem. AddPrintTransformer would work only in interactive, I need a solution that lets me write the formatting into a file, which means formatting inside an application, or inside interactive but printing to a string (sprintf ("%A", o). thx so much for your efforts.

Comment: more and more i think i should take the pretty source code from  fsharp/src/fsharp/utils/sformat.fs and make it into a more flexible library ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think I would just do this:

```ml
[1..1000] 
|> List.take 50
|> List.iter (printf "%A;")
```

Comment: thx scott, i clarified my question. i print a very large object and inside some truncations come up that i want to avoid.

Comment: @citykid I'm afraid that didn't really make your question any clearer to me. Look at the title of your question and consider editing that and your question to home in on what you really want to do. It sounds like you want to know how to pretty print a record, which has nothing to do with lists.

Comment: pretty printing a record is just the context. the question is the question in the title.